# how can i add two numbers using javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
<title> calculator! </title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />


</head>

<body>

first number : <input type="text" name="num1" />
<br><br>
second number : <input type="text" name="num2" />
<br><br>

sum : <input type="text" name="answersum" />
<br><br>

<input type="button" name="add" value ="add" onClick="addnum()" />


<script>
(
function addnum(){

    var num1 = number(document.getElementByName("num1").value);
    var num2 = number(document.getElementByName("num2").value);
    var sum = num1 + num2;

    document.getElementByName("answersum").value = sum;

}


</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

i would like to add two numbers using JavaScript by assigning each number to a variables. but when i click add nothings happens or is there any ways that i can add this two numbers without using a variables? thank you

Comment: getElementsByName is plural - and Number starts with a capital letter so `Number(document.getElementsByName("num1")[0].value)` and you have a weird bracket starting your script `(
function`

Comment: Just an aside. The "answersum" element is just what the [<output>](http://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#the-output-element) element was invented for.

Comment: noted sir thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

**N** of `Number` (you wrote `number`) should be in caps and `getElementsByName` is plural and returns a collection

```
function addnum(){    
    var num1 = Number(document.getElementsByName("num1")[0].value); 
    var num2 = Number(document.getElementsByName("num2")[0].value);
    var sum = num1 + num2;
    document.getElementsByName("answersum")[0].value = sum;
}
```

Comment: Upvoted, though clearly [you need more jQuery](http://needsmorejquery.com/).

Comment: @JamesThorpe I though OP hasn't tagged question with jquery so I didn't suggested jquery based solution.

Comment: `getElementsByName` is plural...

Comment: I wouldn't post a jQuery solution even if it was tagged as such - it's a long running meme on SO... go look at the link...!

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I realized it as well. Thanks though

Comment: The amazing thing about that needmorejquery site is that it uses an unminified version of jQuery to render the page which is simply an image. I sincerely hope that's irony. @JamesThorpe

Comment: @Andy haha - I hadn't looked at the source, I strongly suspect that's the point :)

Answer (score 2):

**parseInt(string, radix);**

Parameters

*string*
The value to parse. If string is not a string, then it is converted to a string (using the ToString abstract operation). Leading whitespace in the string is ignored.

*radix*
An integer between 2 and 36 that represents the radix (the base in mathematical numeral systems) of the above mentioned string. Specify 10 for the decimal numeral system commonly used by humans. Always specify this parameter to eliminate reader confusion and to guarantee predictable behavior. Different implementations produce different results when a radix is not specified, usually defaulting the value to 10.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function addNumbers()
                {
                        var val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value1").value);
                        var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value2").value);
                        var ansD = document.getElementById("answer");
                        ansD.value = val1 + val2;
                }
```

```html
first number :
<input type="text" name="num1" id="value1" />
<br>
<br>second number :
<input type="text" name="num2" id="value2" />
<br>
<br>sum :
<input type="text" name="answersum" id="answer"/>
<br>
<br>

<input type="button" name="add" value="add" onclick="addNumbers()" />
```

Comment: `getElementsByName`, and `parseInt` takes an (optional) index but it's good practice to include it.

Comment: man works for me. ur a blessing to me :) hehe thank you soo much

Comment: @expert123..please mark as accepted, if its really work for u.